# Book About Mermaids and Medusa

Tags: story-identification, books

This book is about a girl who has Medusa like hair, and her enemy is a mermaid, but it has comic scenes and also actually book scenes. I remember that her sister drowned in a lake. I don't remember exactly what it was called but it had a blue cover with a girl on it.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)